# How to make canvas screenshot with proper dimensions?

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, jspdf

I need to convert to pdf screenshot of my form. I followed the tutorial and there was code

```
var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');  
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
      // Few necessary setting options  
      var imgWidth = 208;   
      var pageHeight = 295;    
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;  

      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
      let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
      var position = 0;  
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)  
      pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
    });
```

Everything seems normal, but when I capturing screenshot and inserting in pdf it is cropped and not inserted at top of the pdf document.

here is the [screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/9HfuG0zXoeZoz0F9HMZMKQlhSLdKWq) of results
and here is my initial form [screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/RADMxblVEdJpepztD2L4ozIcSV38eO). Maybe it is because I use angular-material? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try with `pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, 0, undefined, undefined) ` .

Comment: @GauthamK unfortunately not helped. the problem is that the taken screenshot has a lot of whitespace.

Comment: Did you solve it? If not you can re-position your image when placing on the PDF.
`addImage(imageData, format, x, y, width, height, alias, compression, rotation)`
x and y take inputs as to where the image is to be placed.

Comment: @GauthamK I solve it, but I refused to use html2canvas and instead took another library [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image). The problem for me is that html2canvas not recognize HTML element position well and all its inner styles

Comment: Well that's true. Glad you found an alternate way.